# NSMutableArray crashing at runtime

Tags: objective-c, crash, runtime, nsmutablearray

I'm getting a crash at runtime when try to access an NSMutable array that is correctly loaded.
here is the code

```
NSMutableArray *gameItems;

-(id) init
{
       if( (self=[super init])) {

         //initialize array       
        gameItems = [NSMutableArray array];

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            GI *gameItem = [[GI alloc] init];
            gameItem.image = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"triangle.png"];
            gameItem.Position = ccp(140+40*i,200);
            [gameItems addObject:gameItem];
            [gameItem release];
            NSLog(@"%d",[gameItems count]); //SHOWS THE SIZE OF THE ARRAY INCREMENTING CORRECTLY
        }
        NSLog(@"%d",[gameItems count]); //show " 3 " correct !

        for(GI *gameItem in gameItems)
        {
            [self addChild:gameItem.image]; 
             NSLog(@"%d",[gameItems count]);  //show 3 correct !
        }
        [self schedule:@selector(callEveryFrame:)];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) callEveryFrame:(ccTime)dt
{
    NSLog(@"----->%d",[gameItems count]); //CRASHES AT RUNTIME IN THIS LINE
}
@end
```

Please somebody explain me why is this happening.
Could the autorelease feature of the NSMutableArray be the problem?

Comment: @Krypton - I don't think this is the case. The Apple docs say that [NSMutableArray array] creates and returns an empty array. I could be wrong, but I'm under the impression that this does the necessary allocation.

Comment: where is the "mark as correct answer" ?
Krypton you were correct.

Comment: I will repost it as an answer :) Happy to help!

Comment: there seems to be a difference.
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array]; //creates an empty array and I can add objects to it. but it crash the app when calling the array from another function

Comment: while 
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
created the array too, but it seems to stay in memory until I release it.
well, thank u guys...
j0k u were right too that's why I used [NSMutableArray array] in the first place....

Comment: if you are not allocating array then it is automatically release after method finish because it has autorelease . see below link      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844188/initialize-nsmutablearray-nsmutablearray-array

Comment: @priyanka -- it just hit me -- you're right. [[NSMutableArray array] retain] is what OP would have had to do.

Comment: The convention is that a method whose name does **not** begin with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” returns an autoreleased object. The `array` method is no exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(reposted on request)

If your array gameItems is a member, which it seems it is, to be able to access it in other functions such as callEveryFrame then surely you need to have initialised it in this way: `gameItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`;

(you missed the alloc I reckon)